# Script Linux para mandar e-mail do resultado do comando find

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, unix

Eu preciso de uma ajuda em um script para enviar um resultado por e-mail de uma pesquisa (find) e executar todos os dias às 08:00 sem usar contrab no linux

Comment: Sem usar `cron`? Fiquei curioso agora como seria a solução

Comment: Quando se envolve horário amigo é `cron` mesmo a não ser que seu script fique em loop infinto e fica verificando a hora e tals.